# Python subprocess read output line by line

Tags: python, input, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run a python script (`test.py`) from `main.py` using `asyncio.subprocess` and basically, it works fine if `test.py` doesn't have any interactivity i.e. if there's no user interaction.

When my script contains `input(prompt)` with some prompt, basically the prompts isn't get displayed back from the subprocess, as it because of the `await process.stdout.readline()` and `input()` write the prompt out to the `sys.stdout`.

Below is the code for `main.py`

```py
import asyncio
import sys

async def main():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('python3', '-u', 'test.py',
                                                   stdin=sys.stdin,
                                                   stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        data = await process.stdout.readline()
        if not data:
            break

        print(";", data.decode().strip())
    await process.wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

`test.py`

```py
# import time
# for i in range(10):
#   time.sleep(0.5)
#   print(i)
print('hello, world!')
n = input('name: ')
print(f'hey {n}!')
```

When I run `main.py` it waits for the input but prompt isn't visible, here the acutal result

```bash
python3 main.py
; hello, world!
s
; name: hey s!
```

Here's what I expected

```bash
python3 main.py
; hello, world!
; name: s // here it should wait for user input
; hey s!
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**Update**

`test.py` with `flush=True` - This too didn't help in any way. It would be better not to make any changes to the `test.py` as I will be passing the `data` to the client (web browser).

```py
# import time
# for i in range(10):
#   time.sleep(0.5)
#   print(i)
import sys
print(file=sys.stdout , flush=True)
print('hello, world',file=sys.stdout ,  flush=True)
sys.stdout.flush()
n = input('name: ')
print(f'hey {n}!', file=sys.stdout , flush=True)
```

Comment: This isn't asyncio-specific -- it's a problem you'd see with regular synchronous I/O as well. Flush stdout in your subprocess -- that is to say, add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print`, or make it `print(i, flush=True)`. Flushing is only automatic when output goes to a TTY, not when it goes to a FIFO/pipe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I even tried that by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` yet I didn't get the expected output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I now even added `flush=True, file=sys.stdout` to all `print()` and this too didn't help

Comment: CNR. Works fine at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/ConcreteForthrightBookmark#main.sh; can you assemble a reproducer that someone who's not you can run to see the problem?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to run the code in `replit`'s shell and it displayed `; name: hey My Name!` on the same line of input's prompt. I want it to be on a separate line and wait for a user to input, (`data`) so that I can pass it back to the client code.

Ps. I'm trying to replicate [this](https://www.online-python.com/), and I've pasted the minimal reproducible code above.

Comment: Say, for example, I need something like  `; name: John` (user entered John and clicked Enter), then on the next line `; hey John!` is printed back by the `subprocess`

Comment: Re: the replit code -- that's because we have `< <(sleep 1; echo "My Name"; sleep 10)` redirecting stdin from a source that waits a second, writes "My Name" to input, and then continues to sleep. Fork it and take that out if it's not what you want.

Comment: And yes, `input()` gets caught up, because Python (ill-advisedly, unlike UNIX shells) writes the prompt to stdout instead of stderr. My approach to fixing that would be not to use `input()`'s prompt-writing capability but instead write your prompt to stderr explicitly.

Comment: When trying to control an interactive process, `pexpect` can simplify it.